# Closing a connection causes stored procedure changes to rollback

Tags: python, sql-server, transactions, pyodbc

Upon closing a connection, deletion done by stored procedure `DeleteSproc` is getting rolled back. What's wrong with this code?

```
try:
    sql = '{CALL dbo.DeleteSproc (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}'
    values = (c['brandId'],c['requestUuid'],c['registrationUuid'],i['tuid'],i['tpid'],c['status'],c['responseType'],i['BookingItemIds'])

    connBS = pyodbc.connect(l['connectionStrings'][0])
    cursorBS = connBS.cursor()
    rv = cursorBS.execute(sql, values)

    sql = '{CALL dbo.StatusProc (?,?,?)}'
    values = (c['requestUuid'],i['tuid'],i['tpid'])
    
    cursorBS.execute(sql, values)
    rows = cursorBS.fetchall()
finally:
    cursorBS.close()
    connBS.close()
```

Comment: Try `connBS.commit()`

Comment: won't it be autocommit in python?

Comment: [_autocommit is set to False on the pyodbc connection (False is the default)._](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Database-Transaction-Management)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by putting COMMIT at the end of the stored procedure.

Comment: There are some cases where Python DBAPI connectors (of which pyodbc is one example) can get confused if the DBAPI layer implicitly creates a transaction and then the stored procedure does its own transaction-y stuff. It's not necessarily a problem; just something to keep in mind.